# Control representation of custom S4 class in matrix

Tags: r, matrix, r-s4

If I use a custom class, instantiate it, and add it to a matrix, can I control how the output looks?

For example, I have a class `cell` I instantiate and add to a matrix. When I `show` the matrix, it shows up as a questionmark. Can I control how this output looks?

```
setClass("cell", representation(a="character", b="character"))

setMethod("show", "cell",
          function(object) print(paste(object@a,'|',object@b))
)

cell1<-
  new("cell", a="hello", b="world")

mat1<-
  matrix(c(cell1))


> print(cell1)
[1] "hello | world"
> print(mat1)
     [,1]
[1,] ?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately `print` does not appear to dispatch on the sub-components of an object after an initial dispatch, which is terribly annoying but likely done for efficiency reasons.  Here is a work around:

```
setMethod("as.character", "cell", function(x, ...) paste(x@a, '|', x@b))    
cell_matrix <- function(...) {
  structure(matrix(...), class="cell_matrix")
}
print.cell_matrix <- function(x, ...) {
  mat.char <- lapply(x, as.character)      
  dim(mat.char) <- dim(x)
  print(mat.char)
}
mat1 <- cell_matrix(c(cell1, cell1, cell1, cell1), nrow=2)
mat1
```

Produces:

```
     [,1]            [,2]           
[1,] "hello | world" "hello | world"
[2,] "hello | world" "hello | world"
```

Here I got lazy and mixed S3 and S4 classes, but if you're doing this in a package, you may want to implement an S4 `cellMatrix` class, and define an `as.character` method for that class, rather than just for a single cell.

Note that this is likely to be relatively inefficient as you are creating objects for each cell, and you are then iterating through each cell.  I would create vectors that contain all the `a` values for all cells, and all the `b` values for all cells, and then create logic that makes it look like the elements are individual.  Things will be much faster that way.